# Weekly job matches don't match preferred locations

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I have put several different "where you'd like to work" locations in my "match preferences" profile but the weekly job e-mail includes only jobs nearby... and I don't even have the "Always include your current location" option selected.